# Keyboard backlight sensor doesn't work on a Sony Vaio VPCS116FG

Tags: 11.10, drivers, laptop, vaio, backlight

I have a VAIO laptop (VPCS116FG, S series). Its keyboard has sensors that can detect how bright the surrounding is, so it automatically turns on the backlight in dark places such as airplane cabins. Since I've moved to Ubuntu from Windows 7, the backlight sensor doesn't work at all.

By googling the issue, I found [this website](http://code.google.com/p/vaio-f11-linux/wiki/AutoDimmingBacklightDaemon) and followed the instructions, but at the compilation step, I was met with the following errors:

```
sa/file_funcs.c: In function ‘get_first_backlight_device_name’:
sa/file_funcs.c:44:9: warning: format ‘%li’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/tmp/ccIhKx5v.o: In function `handle_acpi_events':
acpi_funcs.c:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `log'
acpi_funcs.c:(.text+0x109): undefined reference to `log'
acpi_funcs.c:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to get the thing to compile by making one slight adjustment to the `compile` file:

Line 16 reads:

```
$CC $CFLAGS $LDFLAGS $DEFINES -o $OUTPUT $SRC_DIR/*.c
```

Change it to:

```
$CC $CFLAGS $DEFINES -o $OUTPUT $SRC_DIR/*.c $LDFLAGS
```

---

**Alternatively,** you can issue the following two commands *right before running `./compile`*:

```
echo -e "16c16\n< \$CC \$CFLAGS \$LDFLAGS \$DEFINES -o \$OUTPUT \$SRC_DIR/*.c\n---\n> \$CC \$CFLAGS \$DEFINES -o \$OUTPUT \$SRC_DIR/*.c \$LDFLAGS" >compile.patch
patch compile compile.patch
```

Comment: The Makefile is non-standard which causes the problem with the order of the arguments. It invokes the compiler to compile all C files in one go, which it should compile them one at a time.

Comment: @user4124: It's not using a makefile - it's just a really simple Bash script. Not a recommended practice of course.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I did it but the sensor still doesn't work, I guess it's 'bin' which causes the problem, getting the error "no such file or directory". do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Explorer: Try creating the 'bin' directory with `mkdir bin` and trying the `./compile` command once more.

Comment: With @GeorgeEdison's help, I've realized that it's a bug and should be reported.

Answer (score 5):

I am on VAIO [VPCS123FG S Series](http://www.sony-asia.com/product/vpcs123fg).
Googled the same issue and found a solution for my machine.

Enter the following command in the terminal:

> echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight

<sup>Thanks to [TechArena Community](http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1442941.htm#post5503994).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

These `log()` and `pow()` are math functions, and you need to make a tiny change to the `compile` file in order to make it work.

Specifically, open the `compile` file and replace

```
CFLAGS="-Wall -W -O2 -march=native -pipe"
```

with

```
CFLAGS="-Wall -W -O2 -lm -march=native -pipe"
```

The change will enable the math library 'libm' and the program will compile just fine!

Comment: Thanks. I just did it but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem.